# How to detect cpu usage of sdks

Tags: android

Is there a way to see cpu usage of SDKs which implemented in android application? I tried to show it on `profiler` tab but couldn't see it. Is there a way to achieve it?

Image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87h2.png]